# create-react-native-app / expo with Relay Modern

Tags: relay, expo, create-react-native-app

Can we use Relay Modern with Expo?

In the docs at https://docs.expo.io/versions/v17.0.0/guides/using-graphql.html, only Apollo client is mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes it is possible, i'm using it for one of my project and it works nicely...

although, it got a little warning

> Warning: Installed version 1.0.0-rc.4 of 'react-relay' does not
>   satisfy required version dev

but it will still run nicely, just beware of the android part it might be have trouble running on it, but this thread gives the solution

https://github.com/facebook/relay/issues/1704#issuecomment-297982006

Comment: Hi @Bondan, do you have some more information on how you managed to get expo play nicely with a relay modern api?

Comment: Yes it would be great to have a bit more information on how you got it working if you have the time.  I'm trying, but getting the error I reported here https://forums.expo.io/t/using-relay-modern-expo-with-babel-plugin-relay/14719

`The package at "node_modules/babel-plugin-relay/lib/getDocumentName.js" attempted to import the Node standard library module "path". It failed because React Native does not include the Node standard library. Read more at https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/introduction/faq.html#can-i-use-nodejs-packages-with-expo`